# django how to distinguish user's email ?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to user register their email's end "ac.uk". 
if it is not, they got some messages.

i do not know how to handle.. plz help me..
 if not request.FILES['email'].endswith("ac.uk"): bring MultiValueDictKeyError at /LanguageExchange/.

this is my view.

```
def register(request):
 registered = False
 if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():       
        if not request.FILES['email'].endswith("ac.uk"):
             messages.warning(request, 'You need to use ac ID', extra_tags='alert') 
             return redirect('/LanguageExchange/')
        else:
            user = user_form.save()
            user.save()
            if 'Profile_image' in request.FILES:
                user.Profile_image = request.FILES['Profile_image'
                user.save()
                registered = True

    else:
        print(user_form.errors)

else:
    user_form = UserCreationForm()

return render(request,
            'LanguageExchange/register.html',
            {'user_form': UserCreationForm,
            'registered': registered})
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the `MultiValueDictKeyError` because `email` is not a file field - the value is in `request.POST` not `request.FILES`. However you should avoid accessing data from `request.POST` where possible, and use `form.cleaned_data['email']` instead.

Having said that, it would probably be nicer to validate the email inside the form, rather than redirecting in the view.

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if not email.endswith('ac.uk'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('You need to use ac ID')
        return email
```

Then you can replace `UserCreationForm` with `MyUserCreationForm` and remove the email check from your view.

In your view, you pass `user_form` to the template context, so that you can see any form errors.

```
return render(request,
             'LanguageExchange/register.html',
             {'user_form': user_form,
              'registered': registered})
```

Comment: oh thanks it is working,but i want user to see the message like 'You need to use ac ID' when they  typed wrong email..

Comment: If you fix your `return render(...)` statement to use the form, then you will see any form errors in the template.

Comment: I've updated my answer - you need to return the value from the `clean_email` method.